# Display image of child element in wordpress

Tags: images

I currently display a list of children of a particular parent as below:

```
            <?php global $post;
                wp_list_pages( array(
                'child_of' => $post->ID, // Only pages that are children of the current page
                'depth' => 1 ,   // Only show one level of hierarchy
                'sort_order' => 'asc'
            ));
        ?>
```

How do I display images next to them? And is there a chance to style them in a way I want or is it always going to be displayed in some UL (just like it does now)

Comment: `wp_list_pages()` is just for creating an unordered list. If you want to query certain pages and display them however you want you will need to use `WP_Query()`.

Comment: Thank you @JacobPeattie. wp_list_pages() solved my problem. Regards.